# Mongoose: moment().format not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

Im having Mongoose schema as follows:

```
createdOn: {
    type: String,
    //default: Date.now,
    default: moment(new Date(Date.now())).format('MMM Do YY')    //npm install moment --save   # npm
},
updatedOn: {
    type: String,
    //default: Date.now
    default: moment(new Date(Date.now())).format('MMM Do YY') 
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After changing the type to String,

I get :

**Fri Jul 28 2017 14:43:40 GMT+0530 (IST)**

How to remove the time and SMT.

I need to keep only Fri Jul 28 2017

I installed Moment package of node js  (http://momentjs.com/)

Whats wrong in my schema above:

I get

> MongooseError: Cast to date failed for value "Aug 7th 17" at path "updatedOn"
>
> message: 'Cast to date failed for value "Aug 7th 17" at path "updatedOn"',
>     name: 'CastError',
>     stringValue: '"Aug 7th 17"',
>     kind: 'date',
>     value: 'Aug 7th 17',
>     path: 'updatedOn',
>     reason: undefined }

Comment: As far as I know mongoose and Mongo uses ISO-dates as date format. "Aug 7th 17" is therefore not valid. If you absolutely want to save it like that you would have to change the type to "String" instead of date. A better solution is perhaps using moment to change the format after you have plucked the data from the database.

Comment: if you want to save like "Aug 7th 17" then your `type` should be `String` because `"Aug 7th 17"` is a string not `date type`

Comment: @tomtom I'm trying to do what you suggested and still struggling, can you elaborate how to do that exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The double default assignment looks wrong.

```
default: default: moment(new Date(Date.now())).format('MMM Do YY')
```

As a better practice, you should consider just using UNIX timestamps rather than formatted date strings. Timestamps will allow you to **easily track statistics** on the database.

So you could just use the:

```
Date.now() // returns a UNIX timestamp
```

In moment.js a UNIX timestamp:

```
moment().unix()
```

If for some reason you need the timestamp in a string format you could always just do:

```
moment().unix() + ''
```